# Deploying Site Scoped solutions Farm wide (All Site Collections)

Tags: sharepoint-server, solution-package, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to deploy & activate a site scoped wsp to **every** site collection in a Farm?

I have a VS solution scoped to Site. It creates a pre-populated Choice column.
I can build the wsp, Add-Solution via PS, Install-SPSolution via PS.

But it only appears on the Central Admin Site Collection features. I need the feature to be installed & activated on every site collection in the farm and across multiple Web Apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below script, you have to replace the web application url and feature name below.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 $webs =  get-spsite -webapplication "http://www.yoursharepointURL.com"
 $feature = "YourFeatureName" #this might not be what you expect it to be, best to do get-spfeature | Select displayname

  Foreach ($oneweb in $webs)
  {
    write-host $oneweb
    $siteFeature = get-spfeature -site $oneweb | Where {$_.displayname -eq $feature}
    if ($siteFeature -eq $null)
    {
      Write-Host "Activating Site level Features at $oneweb" -foregroundcolor Yellow
      Enable-SPFeature -Identity $Feature -URL $oneweb.URL -Confirm:$False
    }
    else
    {
      Write-Host "Feature $feature is already activated on $oneweb" -foregroundcolor green
    }
  }
```

Read more here: [POWERSHELL TO ACTIVATE A SHAREPOINT 2010 FEATURE ON EVERY SITE COLLECTION IN A WEB APP](http://basementjack.com/sharepoint-2/powershell-to-activate-a-sharepoint-2010-feature-on-every-site-collection-in-a-web-app/)

Comment: Thanks for this. I can do this, I didn't think of the option of doing it via PS. I thought I was missing some config in Visual Studio